# PHP table with dynamic content

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I'm writing a small bit of PHP code which will display a table; the X axis will display a window of the last 14 days and the Y axis will display a list of computers in the first column, the content of each date cell will show the computers state on that date (example below).

```
|Hostname   |1   |2    |3  |
+-----------+----+---------+
|computer1  |OK  |DEAD |OK |
|computer2  |OK  |     |   |
```

I need the table to be fully dynamic - so if a new system is added today; it will show and have a state for today, but not for any previous day. So far so good - however my table isn't getting closed properly - so computer states are getting added vertically, rather than horizontally, so it looks more like this:

```
|Hostname   |1   |2    |3  |
+-----------+----+---------+
|computer1  |OK  |     |   |
|computer2  |OK  |     |   |
|computer1  |DEAD|     |   |
|computer1  |OK  |     |   |
```

Can't figure out a good way of closing the table, whilst maintaining accurate, dynamic content. The code for the table is included below (this is missing the hostname column btw):

```
<?php
  $dates2 = mysql_query("SELECT day, month, year, hostname FROM log WHERE date >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -14 DAY) ORDER BY date;");
?>

<?php
  echo "</thead>";
  echo "<tbody>";
  echo "<tr>";
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($dates2))
    {
      echo "<td><a href='/log/" . $row['hostname'] . ".log'>" . $row['hostname'] . "</a></td>";
      $state_date = mysql_query("SELECT state FROM log WHERE hostname = '" . $row['hostname'] . "' AND day = '" . $row['day'] . "' AND month = '" . $row['month'] . "' AND year = '" . $row['year'] . "' ORDER BY date;");
      while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($state_date))
        {
          if(isset($row2['state']))
            {
              if ($row2['state'] == 'ok')
                 {
                   echo "<td bgcolor='#FF0000'>" . $row2['state'] . "</td>";
                 }
              elseif($row2['state'] == 'dead')
                 {
                   echo "<td bgcolor='#00FF00'>" . $row2['state'] . "</td>";
                 }
              else
                 {
                   echo "<td bgcolor='#FFD732'>" . $row2['state'] . "</td>";
                 }
            }
          else
            {
              echo "<td>Unknown</td>";
            }
         }
  echo "</tr>";
  }
  echo "</tbody></table>";
  mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Could you perhaps also post the table that is being generated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put the <TR> part inside the loop. TR is the row.  You're putting everything on one row.

```
while (...)
{
   echo "<tr>";
   ...
   echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks dude! Easier than expected :D

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to iterate through the hosts:

```
$hostnames = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT hostname FROM log WHERE date >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -14 DAY) ORDER BY date;");
while($hostname_row = mysql_fetch_array($hostnames))
{
    $dates2 = mysql_query("SELECT day, month, year, hostname FROM log WHERE date >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -14 DAY) AND hostname = '" . $hostname_row['hostname'] . "' ORDER BY date;");
    echo "<tr>";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($dates2))
    {
      if(isset($row2['state']))
        {
          if ($row2['state'] == 'ok')
             {
               echo "<td bgcolor='#FF0000'>" . $row2['state'] . "</td>";
             }
          elseif($row2['state'] == 'dead')
             {
               echo "<td bgcolor='#00FF00'>" . $row2['state'] . "</td>";
             }
          else
             {
               echo "<td bgcolor='#FFD732'>" . $row2['state'] . "</td>";
             }
        }
      else
        {
          echo "<td>Unknown</td>";
        }
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are your problems:

1. replace **thead** with **table**
2. you should put **tr** and **/tr** tags inside of while loop
3. add an **elseif** for when **$row2['state']** is empty string. in this case output should be **&nbsp;** instead of empty string

Comment: Point 3 is very useful, thanks - something I'd not considered (at this point in time, my data is fully populated).